# upgrade Swift Compiler

Tags: swift, command-line, upgrade

I have installed the latest version of Xcode (12.4). Due to the way this project I'm working on is set up I need to build some dependancies using command line tools. The tool complains that

```
Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28) and the local version is 5.3.1 (swiftlang-1200.0.41 clang-1200.0.32.8).
```

I went to the [swift site](https://swift.org/download/), downloaded, and installed 5.3.3. When I run `swiftc -version` it still claims that I'm running 5.3.1. I've tried rebooting my machine just in case that was the issue but it still claims I'm using the older compiler. What am I missing?

Comment: Does `xcode-select -p` in the terminal prints a path towards Xcode 12.4 application?

Comment: @gcharita it says /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Comment: Try running `sudo xcode-select -s <path-to-xcode-12-4>`.

Comment: @gcharita well it's an improvement. The tool is now complaining that I'm using a version that's too new.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [swiftenv](https://github.com/kylef/swiftenv) utility for simple management of Swift versions. It can manage both global and per project Swift versions